# How to open a popup inside the block? Magnific-popup

Tags: javascript, magnific-popup

How to specify a container in which to open the popup?
[Example img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LxtB.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [THIS](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/) plugin, then edit CSS classes like `.mfp-bg` and/or `.mfp-wrap` to get what you want.

No need for new container, just edit existing one.